# Is nesting CSS selectors possible with Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, nested

Nesting CSS is a very awesome feature in the CSS-PreProcessors like LESS, SASS, Stylus etc. But SASS has Ruby as dependecy while LESS & Stylus require Node. Due to some restrictions I can neither use Node nor Ruby  or any javascript library. But I require the nesting feature greatly so that I can save my time, but I can't have dependencies. I was thinking if Vanilla Javascript can do my work. I assume something like this :

Input :

```
 body {
     h1 {
        color: blue;
        &:hover {
            color: red;
        }
  }
```

Output :

```
 body h1 {
    color: blue;
 }
 body h1:hover {
    color: red;
 }
```

So, is this possible to achieve with Vanilla Javascript ? ( No problem with ES6 or ES6+ ) If yes please teach me how. If no than what can I do ?

Comment: You mean is it possible to write another css preprocessor with javascript? Or the current CSS version allows these kind of things? Any way, the answers are : YES, NO.

Comment: *Due to some restrictions I can neither use Node nor Ruby or any javascript library* Why reinvent the wheel? Best to figure out a way around those restrictions

Comment: I just wanted to know if javascript can do that.

Comment: @Certain Performance I understand but that gonna be hard for me